# Magento 2 | Update products based on attribtue value

Tags: magento2, import

I got about 90k products from a supplier with a attribute `partnumber` assigned to it. I want to update our attribute `delivery_time` based on the `partnumber` attribute.

**Example:**
I got arround 50 products with `partnumber` = 140299, now I need to update the `delivery_time` for ALL those products.

How can I do this via import?

Comment: Have you got any import/export module inside your Magento like FireBear? If the import's are frequent or will be, firebear helps you importing xml, excel, google sheet data and it need's only sku and attribute to update, we're using that for almost any kind of import/export operation due to it's speed.

Comment: Im looking for a solution where i dont need to spend ~500$ since we are switching away from magento in the long term, but yea, also had that in mind. @AlanZavagli